# How to debug Silverlight 3 C# Application?

Tags: c#, debugging, silverlight-3.0

How to debug Silverlight 3 C#  Application? Using VS or Blend... or some tool\plugin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here's a discussion on the Silverlight Forums of using VS 2008 to debug Silverlight](http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/t/10005.aspx) - the bonus is they describe the steps while troubleshooting. You can try the same for Silverlight 3; although the discussion centers around a different version, steps are likely similar.

Answer (score 5):

I think we can debug SL 4 application if it is opened through IE! I had already spent 1 hour finding out "why debugging is not working". Somehow tried in IE and it worked perfectly :)

Comment: Correct. I had to set IE as my default browser also. Simply copying a link didn't work

Comment: if i could i would give 10 points for above comment, after trying everything that worked.

Answer (score 3):

Normally this works just by attaching to the Firefox / Browser of choice process.

--Edit
In Visual Studio you'd choose the Debug menu option then Attach To Process, then select Firefox.exe or IExplore.exe.

Comment: Ha-ha... actually Silverlight developer for example some crazy designer - developer just won’t understand how to perform such operation...

Comment: As this is a developer centric q & a site, you should really contextualise your problem by saying you're a designer but not a developer. I'm not sure how much you'd benefit from debugging if you're not a developer?